# api.ai with heroku error with webhook 206 and 500 with pywu

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, dialogflow-es

I got this error after call dh4 pywu:
api.ai:"status": {
    "code": 206,
    "errorType": "partial_content",
    "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error message: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR ErrorId: e7c78c43-614a-43da-95cd-9d6ff1785af7"
  },
heroku:
2017-02-12T04:40:43.807218+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.205.24 - - [12/Feb/2017 04:40:43] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Thanks

[Source](https://github.com/TrungNguyen1909/BotMia)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. change import pywu into from pywu import pywu!